# Stuck "Enter your Apple ID password"

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id, password

I just changed the password of my Apple ID.

When I started using my Mac, several minutes later, the system preferences asked me to enter my password to continue using iCloud. after entering my new password, it hanged. Restarting the mac did not even work, I had to hard shut down the machine.

After the machine is rebooted, it asks me once again to enter the password of Apple ID...

Could anyone help?

**Edit1:**
So it is always stuck as follows:

[image]

Comment: What sort of help are you looking for? To wipe the mac? To set up a new user account? Can you upload a picture of the dialog and explain in a little more detail how it's preventing you from using the Mac?

Comment: I just added a screenshot...

Comment: Do you have 2 factor auth turned on?  If so, you may need to generate an application specific password.

Comment: I don't think I have 2 factor auth turned on...

Comment: I am having the exact same problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the screen image, I would try a couple of things since you should be able to log in to the Mac and do things other than iCloud. Press cancel in the dialog and then check the date/time on the Mac. It should be within 2 minutes of reality if possible.

Then go to Safari and check at https://icloud.com to be sure you can log in and the account isn't locked or having issues.

At that point, you might need to clean out your keychain or try again in the iCloud preference pane. Worst case, you might need to get on the phone/web chat with iCloud support if it's a problem with your account or Apple's servers.

Comment: I had the same problem. Finally solved it removing iCloud and iCloud mail account from the Mac and all references to the account from the keychain, then restarted and added the account again.

Answer (score 0):

Similar scenario happened to me on the "Enter your iPhone passcode screen" while adding my iCloud account to my MacBook Pro. Solution is simple: when you are asked for your 2FA, click that you didn't get the push and use an alternative way... you will have the option to get an SMS code instead. Use that... log in and it will just work :)